# Migrating to .NET 6.0 error on publish: Assets file doesn't have a target for 'net5.0'

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, visual-studio-2022

I'm trying to migrate from .NET 5 to .NET 6. I've installed VS 2022 Community Preview and the Hosting Bundle... and updated everything in NuGet. The project will build without errors but when I go to publish it, I get the following error:

```
Assets file 'D:\Data\CADE.core\FileManager\FileManager\obj\project.assets.json' doesn't have a target for 'net5.0'. 
Ensure that restore has run and that you have included 'net5.0' in the TargetFrameworks for your project.
```

I don't know why it's still looking for .NET 5 nor how to fix this error.

Comment: Probably just delete your `bin` and `obj` folders

Comment: Deleted both, same error.

Comment: Can you check the .pubxml file? Is it still have .net5, id yes then change to .net6

Comment: LOL... I did change both the production and development .pubxml files from 5 to 6.  Now it says the same thing... Except it changed  'net5.0' to 'net6.0'.

Comment: I also did a manual NuGet restore but that didn't change the error.

Comment: TargetFramework says .Net 6.0... changed from 5 so I don't know any other place it would be trying to build 5.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

With everyone's help, I found the solution.  I edited the publishing information and there was a red dot by Target Framework net6.0.  I clicked the drop-down and one of the options was "net6.0-windows".  I selected that and it published correctly.

Comment: Are you using v5.0.11 of the Hosting Bundle?  Does that run the net6.0 application?

Comment: For my project, I had no Target Framework specified in the publish profile at all, which never made any difference in the past. (The TFM is in the csproj file; why would it need to be in the publish profile as well?) Adding the TFM fixed the issue.

Comment: Same as Doug for me - I had to add the TFM <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework> to the publish profile (pubxml)

Comment: Where in Visual Studio did you edit the publishing information?

Answer (score 7):

Although the error seems not to be related to nuget, it is actually related to nuget.

Open a PowerShell window and enter the following command:

```
dotnet new nugetconfig
```

Answer (score 2):

Check restore is working using `dotnet restore` from the command line. It can make any issues with the restore more obvious.

This type of error can occur if a Nuget package source specified in Visual Studio is inaccessible for some reason. You can view configured nuget package sources under Tools > Options > Nuget Package Manager > Package Sources.

Answer (score 1):

In My case. i had opened the solution in VS 2019 and VS 2022. when it tries to restore i think it is restoring with 2019 and building on 2022. closing the VS 2019 and deleting the obj and bin and rebuilding solved the issue

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was migrating from .Net 6 to .Net 7 tried many solutions offered in other posts but it was Vivek Nuna's comment above that was the key for me to "check the .pubxml file". When I updated it to the correct Target Framework it fixed the issue:

```
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <DeleteExistingFiles>false</DeleteExistingFiles>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>false</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>true</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <PublishProvider>FileSystem</PublishProvider>
    <PublishUrl>\\someserver\wwwroot\someapp\</PublishUrl>
    <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish />
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <ProjectGuid>a1e50b13-5370-4e52-86f3-9386c075311e</ProjectGuid>
    <SelfContained>false</SelfContained>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had install from tools->nuget package manager->search for target and install targets. Then cntrol plus f5 and everythings when fine.